# What do I do with these Test modules being populated in a Live Production Environment?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, production-mode

I always thought that if I ran `composer install --no-dev` that test modules in the Dev directory would not be populated but after finding a payment with that processed with "fake payment method", I found out that is not true.

These test modules are found in `dev/tests/integration/_files/Magento/` and are generated from `vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/`. I can just disable them but is that the proper method? I know how to stop the payment issue I mentioned but is there something I am supposed to do to stop the test modules from generating in the dev directory in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

`--no-dev` option for `composer install` command: Skip installing packages listed in `require-dev` section in `composer.json`

Whenever you run `composer install` or `composer update` **and** `vendor/magento/magento2-base` does not exist, composer will install Magento packages and it also generates `bin`, `dev`, `lib`, `phpserver`, `setup` and some files in `app`, `app/etc`, `generated`, `pub`, `var`...

The `dev` directory is for the Developer testing the code, it will be used when a developer runs the appropriate commands, so, normally it does nothing in your production environment. So, you can keep the `dev` directory as it is.

Comment: I am aware of what dev does but the modules in dev in the path that I provided still register. Again I can disable them but was wondering if I can get them to not generate.

Comment: Could you tell me which test module is registered?

Comment: All of them in that directory `dev/tests/integration/_files/Magento/` but for example `Magento_TestModuleFakePaymentMethod`

Comment: How does it affect your site? I mean how do you know these modules running on production?

Comment: bin/magento mo:s | grep Magento_TestModuleFakePaymentMethod
The issue is that module has a default payment config added to it allowing for people to hit the payment api and place an order. I would rather the modules just not populate to begin with

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your project, I never saw Test modules enabled automatically in all environments.

Comment: Sorry, found the modules located in app/code/Magento/ and app/code/magento/ was in the gitignore. This modules might have been created from someone doing an integration test and a bug creating the folders.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12696

Comment: No worries, glad to hear you found the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why test modules are populating or if they aren't supposed to register but there is a section in extra of your composer to ignore files from magento2-base called magento-deploy-ignore.

Update: The modules were created(in app/code/Magento) from
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12696 and `app/code/Magento/TestModules*` was added in the gitignore from when the project was started and the gitignore was copied from https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/files/config-reference-gitignore.html?lang=en

```
...
"extra": {
      "magento-deploy-ignore": {
        "magento/magento2-base": [
          "/dev/tests/integration/_files/Magento/"
        ]
      },
}
...
```

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32888#issuecomment-839076157